# ggplot2 error when fill values are all NA: Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length.out = n) :

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a generic `plot_data(data)` method.  Sometimes the incoming data has all NAs for the variable I use for *fill* and this causes the error

```
Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length.out = n) : 
  'to' must be a finite number
```

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
  y = c(10, 15, 20, 25),
  foo = factor(c(NA, NA, NA, "yes"), levels=c("yes", "no"))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=foo))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")  # works
ggplot(df[1:3, ], aes(x=x, y=y, fill=foo))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")  # error
```

I don't see why the plot shouldn't render in case 2 (just with all grey bars).  Is there an easy way to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fct_explicit_na` from the `forcats` package to make missing values an explicit factor level. (Note that `addNA` from the base package won't work here; the latter adds NA as a level, but won't cause it to show up in plots.)

```
ggplot(df[1:3, ], 
       aes(x=x, y=y, fill=forcats::fct_explicit_na(foo)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Aside: If you do have other values & just want a different default colour for NA ones, you can change the option in `scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "some colour other than grey")`

Answer (score 1):

Kind of yucky...

```
ggplot(df[1:3,], aes(x=x, y=y, if(!all(is.na(foo))){fill=foo})) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

grey means no fill. For example, the following one will give a grey drawing:

`ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

In your example, when the row with `foo = "yes"` was included, the rows with `foo = NA` were actually not filled with colors, and only the last row was filled. However, when the last row was excluded, all the values in column `foo` become `NA`. As the error suggests, the end of `to` in the fill mapping has to be a finite number, not `NA`. A way to circumvent this is to convert `NA` into strings, such as:

`ggplot(df[1:3, ], aes(x=x, y=y, fill=ifelse(is.na(foo), "NA", foo)))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")`